# After windows update explorer now opens C:\Program Files\NVIDIA folder on startup?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, nvidia-graphics-card

Since i did a windows update which installed a NVidia driver update, windows explorer now opens the C:\Program Files\NVIDIA folder every time I start windows.

I've had a look round the usual Run entries in the registry but nothing seems obvious that it would be opening this folder.

Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According this Microsoft Support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=170086), this behavior can occur if there is a incomplete or damaged entry under the following registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

I suggest that you verify, using regedit, that all entries below this registry key refer to valid program files.

Comment: I don't have enough points to edit my question, but here's my registry section for that key, I can't see what could be causing the problem ? http://www.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/8057f5b2-a880-4d0d-969e-38af2a5ee950

Comment: The nwiz entry should be `"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA...nwiz.exe" /installquiet`. Don't copy my text example, just add the quotes.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked, the window still opens and that line remains in the registry.

Comment: It should have worked. Could you post again the registry section as it is after the change?

Answer (score 1):

In the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

The entry for nwiz was:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nView\nwiz.exe /installquiet
```

I added quotes as follows, and it worked correctly:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nView\nwiz.exe" /installquiet
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) utility. If something is auto-started, it will be detected.

Comment: I'm not sure where I need to look in Syinternals, nvidia is mentioned a lot but nothing like "explorer C:\Program Files\NVIDIA" ??

Comment: @Jules: can you save the data (`File|Save`) and post it somewhere?

Comment: OK http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/AutoRuns.txt

Comment: Thats does open but needs to be viewed in a text editor, Firefox shows odd characters when you open it

Comment: Hmm, that looks sane for me. Try disabling (not deleting) all NVIDIA-related entries; that will show if some NVIDIA application is opening the folder.

Comment: disable how ? what with ?

Comment: There's a checkbox left to each entry in Autoruns. By unchecking it, you are disabling that entry without deleting it permanently.